# cv2.aruco and plt.figure causes qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load 'xcb'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, opencv

The following python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cv2 import aruco

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,6))
```

causes the following error:

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x555e3d4d0a60) is not the object's thread (0x555e3db4a0f0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x555e3d4d0a60)

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/r00tr4t/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tested setting the debug flag:

```
export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
```

The complete log can be found here http://ix.io/37V5

**However, if you remove the cv2 part everything works, why is that?**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# from cv2 import aruco

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,6))
```

Tested on:

- ArchLinux 5.9.10-arch1-1
- Python 3.9.3
- cv2.version.opencv_version '4.5.1.48'
- matplotlib.**version** '3.4.1'

EDIT:
Just realized that my code is a bit simplistic and it can be interpreted as cv2.aruco is not installed, however, if I implement this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cv2 import aruco

print(aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_6X6_250))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,6))
```

The result is `<aruco_Dictionary 0x7f14d109db90>` ie it is installed.

Comment: Try changing the import order: `from cv2 import aruco` `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: Haha. For that particular case, that worked, but it did not work in my official code (about 2k rows). It did not work.

Comment: Could you provide the log that you get when you do `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
` with the new import order that I indicate to you? you already have a similar log but my goal is to compare them.

Comment: It's so long that I provided it inside http://ix.io/37V5

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `opencv-contrib-python`

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: I asked a friend to test it on his computer, and there it worked as it should. Perhaps I just need to reboot my computer.  (uptime 141 days)